# How to update void show?

Tags: java, libgdx

`getMusicPlaying` is set to false whenever someone touches the button, but libgdx runs `show` method only once, at the start of the game, hence the music will keep playing forever.

I tried to use the `render` and `batch.begin` instead of `show()` same result.

```
private boolean musicPlaying = true;

button.addListener(new InputListener() {
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
 return true;
}

public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
 setMusicplaying(!musicplaying);
}
});

}
});
}

public void show() {
 if (getMusicPlaying ==true)
  music.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setMusicplaying function, you should add something like music.stop() whenever the argument is false.

Comment: thats why i love stackexchanges websites, thank you